# Filename attribute in chrome.downloads API overrides .json and .har filenames with .txt. How Can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a Chrome Extension that uses [Chrome Downloads API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) to download files. I can download the files with no problem, but having issues with the filename attribute. The files do not download with the extension that I set for them.

## Context

The extension downloads 3 items:

PNG file:

```js
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: url,
      filename: "anImage.png"
    });
```

JSON Formatted file:

```js
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: url,
      filename: "consoleLog.json"
    });
```

[HAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HAR_(file_format)):

```js
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: url,
      filename: "log.har"
    });
```

## Problem

When the **PNG** file is downloaded, it sets the proper filename to `anImage.png`, but for the JSON formatted file, `filename` is set to `consoleLog.json`, but downloads as `consoleLog.txt` and for `log.har` it downloads as `log.txt`. Why is not downloading with the extension format set in `filename`?

Comment: It uses Content-Type header returned by the server. Try using [onDeterminingFilename](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#event-onDeterminingFilename) event instead of filename.

Comment: I added the listener and it still downloads as a txt: ```JavaScript chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(
                        function (downloadItem, suggest) {
                            suggest({filename: "test.har"})
                        }
                    );
                    chrome.downloads.download({
                        url: url
                    });```

Comment: Welp, I guess the response has the wrong Content-Type and Chrome gives it priority, thus ignoring your file extension. You can try reporting it on https://crbug.com. Meanwhile you'll have to download using the standard JavaScript method via a `<a>` element with `download` attribute, the examples are easy to find. If that will also reset the extension, use chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived listener to override the type header.